# How to track query progress in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a plugin or a script that can track the progress of long query in PostgreSQL?

I mean I need to set progress bar value in Java that related to some update query in Postgres. I search over internet, but I just found some paper that not have any official implementation in any RDBMS system.

Comment: It's an incredibly hard problem to produce reliable, accurate progress indication for a query. Query execution times aren't even the same when you execute the *same query* multiple times in a row.

Comment: Not in general, no.  If you show use the query and the execution plan, we *might* be able to recommend something.

Comment: Some techniques were suggested on dba.se, see: [How do I find out how far along my PostgreSQL query is?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50602/)

Answer (score 66):

I found a good answer here: [Tracking progress of an update statement](https://web.archive.org/web/20180310235608/http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2011/11/02/tracking-progress-of-an-update-statement-1101/)

The trick is to first create a sequence (name it as you like):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE query_progress START 1;
```

Then append to your query's WHERE part:

```
AND NEXTVAL('query_progress')!=0
```

Now you can query the progress:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('query_progress');
```

Finally don't forget to get rid of the sequence:

```
DROP SEQUENCE query_progress;
```

Note that this will most likely make your query run even slower and every time you check progress it will additionally increment the value. The above link suggested creating a temporary sequence but PostgreSQL doesn't seem to make them visible across sessions.

Comment: This is cool and creative. It's also really hacky, but oh well... Hopefully, Postgres will give us a real solution one day.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but I think to query the progress it would be better to call the `currval` function: 
`SELECT CURRVAL('query_progress');`
PS: it is possible to call `currval` function after the update query is done, otherwise you will get an error saying: `ERROR: currval of sequence "query_progress" is not yet defined in this session`; in this case you can use this query: `SELECT last_value FROM query_progress;`, it should return a value even if your update query didn't start.

Answer (score 11):

I have figured a way that might help. But further processing may be needed if you would like to implement it into your code like Java and etc.

The way is to examine the page content in order to track the progress.

Postgresql has a extension called pageinspect that can examine the page information of a particular table.

Details here :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html

Also spend some time on understanding postgresql's page layout here

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html

Look at xmin, xmax and ctid in particular

I am assuming **the table the row insertion is following certain order**. Like the table's pkey. And any long update will likely have new page appended.

I am also assuming that **the primary key id is mostly continuous, with little to some gap**. Since it is just an estimation, I think it is OK with this condition.

You **cannot** find out the total page number by doing `SELECT relname, relpages FROM pg_class` though, since it is not updated.

You will hit with an exception if page index is not existed in the strage ( but you will find the page, even if it is not updated in pg_class or so) , so make a little "binary search" on the "page_index" to find the largest page you have. Don't need to be exact.

Use

```
SELECT backend_xid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid = process-id
```

To find your current transcation id.

Use

```
SELECT lp,t_xmin,t_xmax,t_ctid,t_bits,t_data FROM heap_page_items(get_raw_page('relation_name', page_index));
```

In the sample I am working on it may looks like this

> SELECT lp,t_xmin,t_xmax,t_ctid,t_bits,t_data FROM heap_page_items(get_raw_page('foo', 3407000));
>
> lp  | t_xmin | t_xmax |    t_ctid     |          t_bits          |                           t_data
>
> 1 | 592744 | 592744 | (3407000,1)   | 110000000111000000000000 | \xd1100000000000000e4400000000000054010000611b0000631b0000
>
> 2 | 592744 | 592744 | (3407000,2)   | 110000000111000000000000 | \xd110000000000000104400000000000040010000611b0000631b0000
>
> 3 | 592744 | 592744 | (3407000,3)   | 110000000111000000000000 | \xd11000000000000011440000000000007c010000611b0000631b0000

t_data is the data. lp is the tuple index from the item list. t_xmin and t_xmax is the transcation id. And the t_ctid is the point to the tuple within the tuple itself. t_bits is the NULL bitmap if you have null value in your tuple.

*First check to see if t_min = t_max, and t_ctid (page_index, tuple_id) and lp is the same. If so,  check if the t_xmin is the same as your transcation id. If so check data.*

**Be aware of Endian-ness and NULL bitmap. In my case, it is big-endian (LSB first).**

In my example, the first row is valid. And the first BIGINT (8 bytes 16 hex number) is the sorted id I am looking. So on first row the data is

> \xd110000000000000

Which translate to 0x101d (check endian-ness) -->  4305

And I know my largest id is 18209 and smallest_id is 2857. And I seperate the job into 8 parts so

> (18209 - 2857) / 8 = 1919
>
> And this is the first part I ran. so
>
> 2857 + 1919 = 4776

This means that my sub-job starts at 2857 id and currently at 4305. If it hits 4776, this thread is done!

This is

> (4305 - 2857)/ 1919 = 75.5% Done

---

**Limitations**

This will not work with hash value update. In my case, the id happen to order sequentially as the pkey. And the planner trigger a sequential read. This should also work if the planner is doing some sort of btree index scan for update.

Look into [CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) if you are interested in ordering the physical rows in index order.

Again this method is not exact. And with the assumption highlighted above. If used in a program, should use sparsely to prevent extra overhead for the disk I/O

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is an exact answer to what people are looking for, but I have made a simple function that reports back the current state of a table insert by means of measuring its page size over time. This isn't a direct window into what is happening, but it is a good approximate of what/whether anything is happening. It's also a solid measure of the bottom line (how fast a table is being "filled up").

**The function returns a list of table names with the current size (in bytes and human-readable units) and rate of growth for both the table and all its associated indexes.**

** bonus: it also includes temp file activity as well

I use this especially to see the progress of loading a table as well as how fast it is being loaded, which is good for estimating how long it will take (though increasingly less linear for large loads).

Here is a portable function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_build_monitor(
    IN table_or_schema_list TEXT[] DEFAULT NULL
,   IN sample_period INT DEFAULT 10
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    table_name TEXT
,   table_size TEXT
,   index_size TEXT
)
AS
$$
DECLARE
    table_list TEXT[];
    schema_list TEXT[];
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_sizes_loop;
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_sizes_loop (
    table_name_loop TEXT
,   table_size_bytes BIGINT
,   indexes_size_bytes BIGINT
)
;

select
    array_remove(array_agg(case when split_part(poo, '.',2) = '*' then split_part(poo, '.',1) else NULL end), NULL::TEXT)
,   array_remove(array_agg(case when split_part(poo, '.',2) = '*' then NULL else poo end), NULL::TEXT)
FROM unnest(array[table_or_schema_list]) poo
INTO schema_list, table_list
;

INSERT INTO table_sizes_loop

SELECT
    pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename as table_name
,   pg_relation_size(pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename) AS table_size_bytes
,   pg_indexes_size(pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename) AS indexes_size_bytes
FROM pg_tables
WHERE
    pg_tables.schemaname = ANY(schema_list)
OR  (pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename)::text = ANY(table_list)

UNION

SELECT
    'temp_files'
,   temp_bytes
,   NULL
FROM pg_stat_database
WHERE
    datname = current_database()
;

PERFORM pg_sleep(sample_period);

RETURN QUERY

with
    base AS
(
SELECT
    pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename as table_name_loop
,   pg_relation_size(pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename) AS table_size_bytes
,   pg_indexes_size(pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename) AS indexes_size_bytes

FROM pg_tables
WHERE
    pg_tables.schemaname::text = ANY(schema_list)
OR  (pg_tables.schemaname||'.'|| pg_tables.tablename)::text = ANY(table_list)

UNION

SELECT
    'temp_files'
,   temp_bytes
,   NULL
FROM pg_stat_database
WHERE
    datname = current_database()

)
SELECT
    table_name_loop
,   CASE WHEN table_name_loop = 'temp_files' THEN
        pg_size_pretty((base.table_size_bytes - tsl.table_size_bytes)/sample_period) || '/s'
    ELSE
            base.table_size_bytes
        || ' (' || pg_size_pretty((base.table_size_bytes))
        || ') - ' || pg_size_pretty((base.table_size_bytes - tsl.table_size_bytes)/sample_period) || '/s'
    END as table_size
,       base.table_size_bytes
    || ' (' || pg_size_pretty((base.indexes_size_bytes))
    || ') - ' || pg_size_pretty((base.indexes_size_bytes - tsl.indexes_size_bytes)/sample_period) || '/s'
    as table_size
FROM table_sizes_loop tsl
JOIN base USING (table_name_loop)
ORDER BY base.table_size_bytes DESC
;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

To view it, use a select statement like the following, passing a list of schema-qualified tables or something like "schema.*" for the whole schema - and optionally the sample period (default is 10s).

```
select * from table_build_monitor('{public.*}', 3);
```

Comment: not exactly a simple query

Answer (score 2):

For an `INSERT` where you know the total number of rows you're inserting, you can use the query plan to get an idea of the progress:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM test_table;
```

This will return the query plan including the estimated number of rows returned by the query. If it was an empty table this would correspond to the rows already inserted. For a non-empty table you'd have to know the number of rows that were already there before the insert.

```
                              QUERY PLAN                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on test_table  (cost=0.00..6901575.15 rows=300238015 width=4)
(1 row)

Time: 0.463 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to track the "live" progress of a query. In theory, the system could compare top-level progress versus the query-plan, and emit some sort of percentage readout. In practice, I doubt it would be terribly accurate and I doubt the performance impact would be worthwhile.

Comment: Teradata allows exactly what the the question is asking about. See here: https://www.info.teradata.com/download.cfm?ItemID=1005555

Answer (score 0):

If you are just doing an INSERT, this is also a very quick and dirty way of tracking progress similar to recommendations above:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE track_insert;

INSERT INTO your_table
[VALUES | SELECT]
RETURNING nextval('track_insert')
;
```

Then in another session, just track the progress with

```
SELECT pg_sequence_last_value('track_insert')
```

NOTE: make sure you are doing something to paginate the results of the above query otherwise you'll get a potentially large response.

Answer (score -1):

You can add an `update_time` column to your table, holding the value of the last update. If you know somehow which records should be affected, then you can also set their `update_time` to the current time and when you check the progress and you know the number of affected rows, then you can select the number of records affected where the `update_time` is newer than the time when you started the update. Number of affected rows having "new" `update_time` / number of records to update * 100 gives you the progress percent.

Comment: If this is being done in a single statement, no changes will be visible until all are committed.

Comment: True, this is why it is a good idea to separate the updates into batches. For example if you have to update 100 000 records, then separating it into 100 batches applicable for 1000 records each, you will see their change in percentage.

Comment: True, but if he was willing and able to do it that way, he can get the progress indication for free without having to add extra columns, because it is the client that issues the batches.