# How to see update status for long running update queries in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

My questions for postgresql, suppose i have 10 million records in a table and want to update a column for the all rows and running this query takes quite time, while this query is running i want to see the progress of this query i.e how many records this query has updated till now.am not talking about the final status which usually comes after the query finished.

You can also say i want to verbose my update query.

Is this possible.? Kindly Help

Comment: but this has been asked in an interview and was told to find the answer from the internet.

Comment: Well, you found the answer.

Comment: Here's a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212484/how-to-track-query-progress-in-postgresql